# access iframe code behind vb variable from parent javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, iframe

I have searched a lot and tried a few of the things regarding this topic, but nothing has worked for me so far.
I have a .ascx control added to a web page on a domain - say 'x.com' On the same web page, I have an iframe with the src - say 'marketplace.x.com/example.aspx. The aspx page in the iframe has an int variable declared  as a vb variable in the code behind file called counter.

What I'm trying to do, is to get the value stored in this counter variable from a javascript (jquery) function in the .ascx file on the main web page.
Is that possible? Does that count as cross domain?

This is what I have tried:

```
var count = document.getElementById('frame1').contentWindow['counter'];
```

Comment: "Does that count as cross domain?" Yes. The page/variable is in a different domain.